# I have used a count down timer, but it resets itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever i refresh the page the timer resets. It starts from from the begining. I have use the plugin called countdown.js

Here is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var now = new Date();
    var countTo = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + now.valueOf();
    $('.timer').countdown(countTo, function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        switch(event.type) {
            case "seconds":
            case "minutes":
            case "hours":
            case "days":
            case "weeks":
            case "daysLeft":
                $this.find('span.'+event.type).html(event.value);
                break;
            case "finished":
                $this.hide();
                break;
        }
    });
</script>


<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3 timer">
    <div class="days-wrapper" style="text-align:center;">
        <span class="days"></span> 
        <p style="margin-left:-80px;"><br><br>DAYS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hours-wrapper" style="text-align:center;">
        <span class="hours"></span> 
        <p style="margin-left:-80px;"><br><br>HOURS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="minutes-wrapper" style="text-align:center;">
        <span class="minutes"></span> 
        <p style="margin-left:-80px;"><br><br>MIN</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do, then?

Comment: The page refresh makes everything start from zero again, yon can't get what you want without using a server that can store data.

Comment: Or hard coding the time to which count down, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Everytime you reload a page javascripts "forgots" whatever you have done previously and your code is executed entirely from the beginning.

A possible solution is to use some persistent storage method such as [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

In your example, you can do something like:

```
var previousCountTo = localStorage.getItem('time'); 
var now = new Date(); 
var countTo = previousCountTo?parseInt(previousCountTo, 10):(30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + now.valueOf());
localStorage.setItem('time', countTo); // Save the current time.
$('.timer').countdown(countTo, function(event) {
      var $this = $(this);
    console.log(event);
      switch(event.type) {
          case "seconds":
          case "minutes":
          case "hours":
          case "days":
          case "weeks":
          case "daysLeft":
              $this.find('span.'+event.type).html(event.value);
              break;
          case "finished":
              $this.hide();
              localStorage.removeItem('time'); // once finished, remove the timer.
              break;
      }
});
```

Comment: I have tried with your code, Replaced the code with your code but i couldn't find any output

Comment: I had a mistake in that code. I'm storing the "previous" value which is null the first time.

I've fixed it now.

Comment: Are you sure you get an output? I have checked I could see the same. I am still looking into your code.

Comment: The problem is the way Date is converted to JSON (in order to be stored to the localStorage). I've fixed it by storing the countTo variable instead. I've just tried it and seems to work :)

Comment: My bad, localStorage store data as DOMString, so we need to parse the store value first. I've fixed the code. You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/e3UnS/2/

Answer (score 0):

When JavaScript is executed inside a browser, its execution scope is limited to the lifetime of the loaded page.

After the page is unloaded, all the state is discarded, which includes variables and timers. So the answer is ***you cannot do that***.

P.S.: You ***cannot*** preserve variable state after the page is unloaded. This does *not* mean you can get *no* state over the edge. See @tehsis's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24909750/1461424).

Comment: I *guess* the user want the countdown to continue to a certain time, which **can** be done. They just need to hard code it.

Comment: In the age of HTML5, localStorage and WebSQL this statement "you cannot do that." isn't actually true.

Comment: @Regent: True, my answer was incomplete. BTW there was such a thing called "sessions" _well before_ the age of HTML5, localStorage, and WebSQL. :)

Comment: Just take note of webSQL is deprecated in favor of IndexedDB :)

Comment: Well, yes, I forgot that you can solve this problem using even cookies :) @tehsis I have already heard this fact and have already forgotten it. I hope that will not forget about it again, thanks.